# Can someone help me how to make the button from another frame work?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Can someone help with this one? it's a system where you log in and another frame pops up. In that frame you can put 2 words and the frame will tell if the works are the same or not. But the button does not work for some reason. I've been doing this for 4 days and I really need some help.

### Code

```
public class Userinter implements ActionListener  {
    
    //first frame
    private static JLabel userLabel;
    private static JTextField userText;
    private static JLabel passwordLabel;
    private static JPasswordField passwordText;
    private static JButton button;
    private static JLabel success;

    //second frame
    private static JLabel label1;
    private static JLabel label2;
    private static JTextField WordNum1;
    private static JTextField WordNum2;
    private static JButton button2;
    private static JLabel success2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //frame
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        //username
        userLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        userLabel.setBounds(80,80,80,25);
        panel.add(userLabel); 
        
        userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(180,80,165,25);
        panel.add(userText);
        
        //password
        passwordLabel = new JLabel("password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(80,150,80,25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);
        
        passwordText = new JPasswordField();
        passwordText.setBounds(180,150,165,25);
        panel.add(passwordText);
        
        //button
        button = new JButton("Login");
        button.setBounds(80,190,80,25);
        button.addActionListener((ActionListener) new Userinter());
        panel.add(button);
        
        success = new JLabel("set");
        success.setBounds(80,250,300,25);
        panel.add(success);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String user = userText.getText();
        String password = passwordText.getText();
        
        if (user.equals("Gal") && password.equals("Skr")){
            // second frame
            JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel();
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
            frame2.setSize(400,300);
            frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.add(Panel2);
            
            Panel2.setLayout(null);
            
            label1 = new JLabel("Set word/number here:");
            label1.setBounds(10,20,200,25);
            Panel2.add(label1);
            
            WordNum1 = new JTextField();
            WordNum1.setBounds(100,50,165,25);
            Panel2.add(WordNum1);
            
            label2 = new JLabel("Set word/number here:");
            label2.setBounds(10,90,200,25);
            Panel2.add(label2);
            
            WordNum2 = new JTextField();
            WordNum2.setBounds(100,130,165,25);
            Panel2.add(WordNum2);
            
            JButton Button2 = new JButton("Check");
            Button2.setBounds(100,200,80,25);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {
                    String word = WordNum1.getText();
                    String word2 = WordNum2.getText();
                    
                    if(word.equals(word2)){
                        success2.setText("yes");
                    }
                }
            });
            
            Panel2.add(Button2);
            
            success = new JLabel("set");
            success.setBounds(80,250,300,25);
            Panel2.add(success);
                 
        }else
            success.setText("incorrect username or/and password.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` is where I'm going to stop - this is a bad idea

Comment: *But the button does not work* -well we don't know what button you are talking about. In any case you have poorly structured code.  Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). The `ButtonDemo`  which can be found by clicking on the "example index" link is a good place to start for something basic. It will show you: 1) a better structure for your code. 2) how to create a frame with buttons. Then you just modify the ActionListener code to do what you want.

Comment: Also, your popup window should be a JDialog, not a JFrame. Variables names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), it is going to save you a lot of time and head aches.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.EventListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        private LoginPane loginPane;
        private WordPane wordPane;
        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        public MainPane() {
            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            setLayout(cardLayout);

            loginPane = new LoginPane();
            loginPane.addLoginListener(new LoginPane.LoginListener() {
                @Override
                public void didLoginSuccessfully() {
                    cardLayout.show(MainPane.this, "words");
                }

                @Override
                public void didCancelLogin() {
                    SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(MainPane.this).dispose();
                }
            });

            wordPane = new WordPane();

            add(loginPane, "login");
            add(wordPane, "words");
        }

    }

    public class WordPane extends JPanel {

        public WordPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);

            add(new JLabel("Set word/number here:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;

            add(new JLabel("First word:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Second word:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            JTextField firstWordField = new JTextField(10);
            JTextField secondWordField = new JTextField(10);

            add(firstWordField, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(secondWordField, gbc);

            JButton checkButton = new JButton("Check");
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(checkButton, gbc);

            checkButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (firstWordField.getText().equals(secondWordField.getText())) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(WordPane.this, "Words match", "Match", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(WordPane.this, "Words do not match", "Does Not Match", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class LoginPane extends JPanel {

        public interface LoginListener extends EventListener {

            // Probably should pass in the User which was authenticiated,
            // but I'll leave that to you to figure out
            public void didLoginSuccessfully();

            public void didCancelLogin();
        }

        private JTextField userNameField;
        private JPasswordField passwordField;

        private JButton loginButton;
        private JButton cancelButton;

        public LoginPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);
            add(new JLabel("User name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);

            userNameField = new JTextField(10);
            passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);

            DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    fieldsDidChange();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    fieldsDidChange();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    fieldsDidChange();
                }
            };

            userNameField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
            passwordField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            add(userNameField, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(passwordField, gbc);

            loginButton = new JButton("Login");
            loginButton.setEnabled(false);
            loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    performLogin();
                }
            });
            cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    performCancel();
                }
            });

            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
            buttonPane.add(loginButton, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            buttonPane.add(cancelButton, gbc);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(buttonPane, gbc);
        }

        public void addLoginListener(LoginListener listener) {
            listenerList.add(LoginListener.class, listener);
        }

        public void removeLoginListener(LoginListener listener) {
            listenerList.remove(LoginListener.class, listener);
        }

        protected void fireDidLoginSuccessfully() {
            LoginListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(LoginListener.class);

            System.out.println(listeners.length);
            if (listeners.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            for (LoginListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.didLoginSuccessfully();
            }
        }

        protected void fireDidCancel() {
            LoginListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(LoginListener.class);
            if (listeners.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            for (LoginListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.didCancelLogin();
            }
        }

        protected void fieldsDidChange() {
            if (userNameField.getText().length() > 0 && passwordField.getPassword().length > 0) {
                loginButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                loginButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        protected void performLogin() {
            // Peform the authentication
            // In a production system, it would be fesible to have this
            // done via a different class passed into this class
            fireDidLoginSuccessfully();
        }

        protected void performCancel() {
            fireDidCancel();
        }

    }
}
```

As to you "question"

This...

```
button.addActionListener((ActionListener) new Userinter());
```

is going to generate a disconnection between what is displayed on the UI and what you code is going to executing against, as you have two instance of `Userinter`